# insert multiple records from html to db via php

Tags: php, html

So Basically i have a form with this layout[image: the layout]

Let me explain the layout first ,
when ever the user presses the + another row gets added inside the form and vice versa to the -. After filling out the text fields whenever the user presses the add button the values entered within the table must be inserted inside the table, and for this i redirected the form to the php page using get method and lets say the url somewhat looks like

```
host.com/index.html?id=1&name=n1&age=12&location=location1&id=2&name=n2&age=14&location=location2
```

i can segregate the values in the php file using this

```
$_GET['id']; and so on...
```

and now the problem that i'm facing is i can get the values only once, say i can get only the values for the elements in the id 1.
what i want is , i wanna insert the 2 rows in a single query and i'm not able to get multiple row values 
via the method i use

Comment: show us the form code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the fields with square brackets, PHP will create an array of values for you

```
<input type="text" name="myFieldName[]" value="Val1" />
<input type="text" name="myFieldName[]" value="Val2" />
```

Will result in

```
$_REQUEST['myFieldName'][0];  //  Val1
$_REQUEST['myFieldName'][1];  //  Val2
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your input names to the following format

```
name="id[]"
```

When submitted, PHP will transform each key into an array.

Also, you should really use `POST` for this data. I'm not sure why you're *redirecting* anything. Just set the form's `action` attribute to your PHP file with `method="POST"` and submit normally.

Answer (score 1):

Either you use unique request-param-names eg

`id1=`

or you build an `array` by using

`id[]=1&name[]=n1`